# Vue.js - this.$refs.key returns an empty array or undefined instead of element

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, vue-component, ref

I have a component for dialog windows in Vue 2 that is listening to event `tcs-show-confirm` (it is the same event that shows the dialog, sets the `show` property to true - in a parent component):

```
  @Prop({ default: false })
  show: boolean;

  @Prop()
  buttons: Array<TcsDialogButton>;

  mounted() {

    this.$nextTick(function () {
      TcsEventBus.$on('tcs-show-confirm', () => {
        console.log(this.$refs.tcsdialbuttons);
      });
    });
  }
```

A html of the component is here (content of the footer slot is not replaced with another componet's html):

```
  ...
  <slot name="footer">
    <div v-if="buttons && buttons.length" ref="tcsdialbuttons" v-for="(button, index) in buttons">
      <button tabindex="0" class="tcs-button tcs-dialog__button" @click="$emit('close', button.emitString)">
        {{button.text}}
      </button>              
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  </slot>
  ...
```

Problem is that console.log(this.$refs.tcsdialbuttons) shows an empty array [] with length 0. Why is that? How can I access the buttons and set a focus on the first one?

---

I also tried to change fat arrow function to normal function:

```
      TcsEventBus.$on('tcs-show-confirm', function() {
        console.log(this.$refs.tcsdialbuttons);
      });
```

But now it returns undefined.

---

I just found out that I cannot reference any of the elements in the component, even if it works in other components in my project. I don't understand..

Comment: I suspect the issue is with `this` variable. Try replacing the fat arrow function in `TcsEventBus` callback with traditional callback function.

Comment: I tried it and now it returns undefined.

Comment: When are you actually emitting the `tcs-show-confirm` event?

Comment: For example when "log out" is clicked in another component: `TcsEventBus.$emit('tcs-show-confirm', new DialogMessage(DialogMessageType.Confirm, this.onCloseDialog, 'Are you sure?'));`

Comment: @Incredible Do you still need help with this?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest considering these 2 good practices first:

- https://vuejs.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue/rules/no-use-v-if-with-v-for.html
- https://vuejs.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue/rules/require-v-for-key.html

Once that's taken care of, I'd suggest adding an `index` to your `v-for` and adding the `:ref`  to the individual buttons so you can find each one of them in a function.

Working with array items via `ref` is rather well described here: [this.$refs[("p" + index)].focus is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306581/this-refsp-index-focus-is-not-a-function)

You should be able to apply focus to the first button using something like `this.$refs[`button${index}`][0].focus();`

Comment: Looks like a clear and concise answer, unfortunately I'm unable to verify suggested solutions now.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I saw the date this question was asked but wrote an answer anyway - I found myself in a similar situation last year and remembered having a hard time figuring it out.