# this.$refs[("p" + index)].focus is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

I'd like to turn a `div` into input box on click, so that the post (which is rendered inside a loop) can be edited.

Here is the button on the post:

```
<a @click="setFocusEdit(index)" v-if="isAuthor(post)" href="#" >Edit Me</a>
```

And the `div` concerned:

```
<div :ref="'p' + index"  class="post-description">
    {{post.description}}
</div>
```

The method:

```
  setFocusEdit(index) {
    console.log('focusing on', index);

    this.$refs['p' + index].focus();
  },
```

But I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.$refs[("p" + index)].focus is not a function
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is in console? `index` is not `undefined`, right?

Comment: No, the index value in printed in the console.

Comment: [Unrelated comment] Super trippy, had almost the identical issue as you, only with this.$refs['p' + i].focus instead. Imagine my amazement and the sort-of creepy feeling of seeing this as the top result on google ^^;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you're using `v-for` you should use the `ref` attribute with static name like `posts` which gives you an array of the referenced elements

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      posts: [{
          title: "post 1",
          content: "content 1"
        },
        {
          title: "post 2",
          content: "content 2"
        }
      ],

    }
  },

  methods: {
    setFocusEdit(index) {


      this.$refs.posts[index].focus();
    }

  },
  mounted() {

  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>




<div id="app">
  <div class='col-md-4 mt-3' v-for="(post, index) in posts" :key="index">
    <textarea readonly ref="posts" class="post-description">
      {{post.content}}
    </textarea>
    <a @click.prevent="setFocusEdit(index)" href="#">Edit Me</a>
  </div>
</div>
```