# Validation of v-form inside of for loop with dynamic refs

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a problem with the validation of a v-form from vuetify. When I try to validate each tab in a function I get the error message:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.$refs.formTest1.validate is not a function"

Here is my validation function:

```
validateTab() {
  return (
    this.$refs["formTest1"] as Vue & {
      validate: () => boolean;
    }
  ).validate();
},
```

Here is my loop which iterates through every test:

```
        <v-tab-item
          v-for="test in system.test"
          :key="test.key"
        >
```

And here is the Code for the creation of the v-forms for every iteration:

```
<v-form
   :ref="'form' + test.id"
   v-show="test.schema"
   v-model="validationMap[test.id]"
>
   <v-jsf
     // some dialog 
   />
</v-form>
```

My validationMap is a Map that looks like that:

```
validationMap: Map<string, boolean>;
```

with the id as a string and the boolean as the validation.

It seems like that I just can't access the validate() function of v-form and I don't know why.

Also I tried to add an index behind the this.$refs["formTest1"] so it looked like:

> this.$refs["formTest1"][0]

It looked like that solved the issue for a lot of people in another thread:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247537/vuetify-form-refs-validate-is-not-a-function)

But I just got another error in the linter which told me:

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'Vue | Element | (Vue | Element)[]'.   Property '0' does not exist on type 'Vue | Element | (Vue | Element)[]'.

So I ran out of ideas and I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me out:

```
    for (let forms in this.$refs) {
      this.$refs[forms].validate();
    }
```