# vuejs2 vee-validate 3 dynamic radio

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate, formwizard

I am building a Form Wizard with multiple questions, each question has multiple radio options, but i not able to validate each question, always receive and error, heres is the source code

In the variable **poll** are stored the **questions** and each one has the possible **answers**

The Form Wizard hasta a multiple Tabs, each one with a **question** and each one with a radio button for each **answer**

I have tried with one **question** in order to avoid the possible duplicated data, but i was no be able to validate correctly using the vee-validate

I am using **VueJS 2.6.x** and **vee-validate 3.4.14** more specifically using the Vuexy Template and JavaScript not TypeScript

```
<template>
  <div v-if="poll">
    <form-wizard
      color="#7367F0"
      :title="null"
      :subtitle="null"
      layout="horizontal"
      shape="square"
      finish-button-text="Submit"
      back-button-text="Previous"
      class="wizard-horizontal mb-3"
      @on-complete="formSubmitted"
    >
      <!-- Question/Answers details tab -->
      <template v-for="question in poll.questions">
        <tab-content
          :key="question.id"
          :before-change="validationForm"
        >
          <validation-observer
            ref="questionRules"
            tag="form"
          >
            <b-card-text>
              <h4>
                {{ question.question }}
              </h4>
            </b-card-text>

            <validation-provider
              #default="{ errors }"
              :name="'question-' + question.id"
              rules="required|numeric"
            >
              <b-form-radio
                v-for="answer in question.answers"
                :id="'question-' + question.id + '-answer-' + answer.id"
                :key="answer.id"
                v-model="Selected"
                :value="answer.id"
                :name="'question-' + question.id"
                class="mt-2 mb-25"
              >
                {{ answer.answer }}
              </b-form-radio>
              <div class="mt-2">
                <small class="text-danger">{{ errors[0] }}</small>
              </div>
            </validation-provider>
          </validation-observer>
        </tab-content>
      </template>
    </form-wizard>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { FormWizard, TabContent } from 'vue-form-wizard'
import { ValidationObserver, ValidationProvider, extend } from 'vee-validate'
import ToastificationContent from '@core/components/toastification/ToastificationContent.vue'
import 'vue-form-wizard/dist/vue-form-wizard.min.css'
import { required, numeric } from 'vee-validate/dist/rules'

import {
  BFormRadio,
  BCardText,
} from 'bootstrap-vue'
import index from 'vue-prism-component'
import { title } from '@core/utils/filter'
import { codeIcon } from './code'

extend('required', required)
extend('numeric', numeric)

export default {
  components: {
    ValidationObserver,
    FormWizard,
    TabContent,
    BFormRadio,
    BCardText,
    ValidationProvider,
  },
  props: {
    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/require-default-prop
    poll: null,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      required,
      numeric,
      codeIcon,
      Selected: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    formSubmitted() {
      this.$toast({
        component: ToastificationContent,
        props: {
          title: 'Form Submitted',
          icon: 'EditIcon',
          variant: 'success',
        },
      })
    },
    validationForm() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.$refs.questionRules.validate().then(success => {
          if (success) {
            resolve(true)
          } else {
            reject()
          }
        })
      })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

The view is loaded correctly, at least as is expected

[image: The view is loaded correctly, at least as is expected]

Exist a walkaround in case not be possible as i implemented?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64247537/vuetify-form-refs-validate-is-not-a-function)

Is necessary use the [0] index, thanks a lot!

```
validationForm() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.$refs.questionRules[0].validate().then(success => {
      if (success) {
        resolve(true)
      } else {
        reject()
      }
    })
  })
},
```