# Vue: how to set the focus on an input field

Tags: vue.js, focus

when I load the page I would like the focus to go to the input field

```
  <b-form-input
    placeholder="Name *"
    name="name"
    autofocus
  ></b-form-input>
```

but it does not work

how can I do?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54306581/this-refsp-index-focus-is-not-a-function/54309663#54309663

Answer (score 0):

Add a ref to the input :

```
  <b-form-input
    placeholder="Name *"
    name="name"
    autofocus
    ref="nameRef"
  ></b-form-input>
```

then in mounted hook :

```
mounted(){
  this.$refs.nameRef.focus()
}
```

Comment: I tried as you told me, inserting the ref inside the input and the recall inside the mounted but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

When I inserted your code into an HTML file, it just did nothing, nothing showed up. By just removing the `b-form-` it worked and it also focused when I loaded the page without me doing that. So I guess that works, sorta. But I don't quite know vue so I hope that this isn't terribly wrong and the b-form is totally fine, I apologize in that case.

Comment: i tried to remove the b-form- like you told me but it doesn't work.

the b-form- I put it because I'm using boostrap vue

Comment: Okay, sorry, I don't know too much about vue. But just using `<input placeholder="Name *" name="name" autofocus></input>` in an otherwise empty .html worked.